# Convergence of Bernoulli to Normal

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

We are given $Y_n \sim Bern(p_n)$ where $Y_1, Y_2,\dots$ are independent, $0 < a \leq p_n \leq b < 1$, $a$ and $b$ are constants, and

\begin{equation}s_n = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n \mathrm{Var}\, Y_k}\end{equation}

Prove:

\begin{equation}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n(Y_k - p_k)}{s_n} \overset{D}{\rightarrow} Norm(0,1)\end{equation}

I am trying to use the central limit here, but I am having trouble setting this up, as the individual $p_n$'s are not guaranteed to be equal. I feel like I need to show some sort of convergence to a common mean and variance, which would then let me use the central limit theorem. Am I even close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, define $Z_k=Y_k-p_k$ then $E(Z_k)=0$ since in this case you have that $sup_j E(|Z_k|^{2+\epsilon})< \infty$ (Because all of them are Bernoulli and they have finite second moments) then you can get the result from the Central limit theorem for non i.i.d sequences.

See, for example Protter Probability essentials pg. 183